How to install Wifi USB Ugreen AX900
I just got a wifi usb adapter but it's not plug and play, the lsusb gives me this but i can't find information on how to get the correct drivers.
Already tried THIS but it does not work.
LSUSB gives me this:


I got the same USB wifi Ugreen AX900 adapter and noticed the same. When I plugged it into my Linux machine it found the adapter as USB storage of about 3MB with the Windows installer on it.
I booted into Windows and ran the installer from the storage on the adapter.
Once I had run the installer the stick now appears as the WiFi adapter in both Windows and Linux.
It shows up as:
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 368b:8d85 AICSemi AIC 8800D80

It looks like while running the Windows setup it does something to the adapter and switches it from a storage device to a WiFi adapter permanently, interesting.


Thanks, sadly, I don't have double boot to test it. In the end I asked for a refund and sent it back. Thanks

Do you have any mates with a windows install ? you could borrow for 2 minutes ? and do the switch on there machine.?
